# How to apply this line np.add.reduce(x) to a list contains multiple arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm learning Python and I faced this line `b = add.reduce(a).`For instance, the below example will give me an array with `one row` and `15 cols` and I will add them by this line `b = add.reduce(a)`:

```
from numpy import *
a =arange(15)
b = add.reduce(a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

My problem is:

Can I do this with a list contains multiple arrays?... This is below my try:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[np.arange(1,6)],
     [np.arange(1,5)],
     [np.arange(1,10)]]
print(np.array(x))
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(np.add.reduce(i))

print(y)
```

It gives me this output:

```
[[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
 [array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
 [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]]
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Comment: `[add.reduce(i[0]) for i in x]`?

Comment: @Divakar Thank you so much, dear. Could you tell me what is the benefit of zero in i? i[0]

Comment: Your list is a list of list of arrays, not a list of arrays. So, compensates with that 0.

Comment: @Divakar Aha... I got it